# Sencha Touch 2.0 Multiple List Item Buttons

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Does anyone know if it is possible to have multiple icon buttons on a Sencha Touch list item that listen to different events?  If so, how can I accomplish this?

For instance, say I have a list of people and there's an icon for email, phone and a map to their location for each person.  I want to show 3 small icons and be able to map each icon to do 3 separate actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how you are creating your buttons.

If the buttons are simple HTML using `itemTpl`, you can just listen to the [itemtap](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView-event-itemtap) event on List and use the `event` argument to detect which button you pressed. You could do this via a custom attribute or even a className:

```
myListItemTapListener: function(list, index, target, e) {
    var el = Ext.get(e.getTarget());
    if (el.hasClass('map')) {
        this.navigate(index);
    } else if(el.hasClass('email')) {
        this.email(index);
    } else if(el.hasClass('phone')) {
        this.phone(index);
    }
}
```

If your buttons are actual `Ext.Button`'s inside a component List, you can simply add a listener onto each button when you create the component. There is an example of how to do this in the [DataView Guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/dataview) in the Sencha Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Component DataView may help you. You can see this [guide]: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/dataview-section-4

I have wrote a [demo]: https://github.com/hs3180/Sencha-Touch-Component-DataView
, in app/view/,

- Main.js, a dataview component with ***useComponets*** true, and set ***defaultType*** to 'demo.view.Item'.
- Item.js, a DataItem, the visible content of each item is a panel ( in Card.js ). I use datamap to link **name** in record ( within store ) to **userName** ( in demo.view.Card ).
- Card.js, a Panel for each person. A user name title and 3 buttons.